# What should I do to prepare a player for his character's death

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, character-death

You know a player character is going to die next session, mainly thought the stupidity of his actions (I would have to fudge too many dice rolls for him to survive).  You know your player is likely to leave the group if his character dies.  What can and should you do to prepare the player and make sure they don't leave the group?

Just an update:
Unfortunately we've already had the session and as expected his character died.  He stormed off from the table and hasn't responded to our emails or phone calls.  Unexpectedly the other players in the group are happy he's gone.  So it has all worked out for the best I guess, but I'm sure some other DM will have this question one day.

My answer is go ahead and kill the char and let the player leave the group.

Comment: I feel like we need to know what the character has done. *Why* are you so certain they are going to die?

Comment: Also what are those "obvious hints" you are talking about?

Comment: Especially bearing in mind that the first hint gets missed, the second hint gets ignored, and the the third hint gets misunderstood.

Comment: From how the question is currently worded, we know nothing about the situation other than that you think the character will die *and*  we know nothing about the player other than that they tend to make bad tactical decisions. I don't think that is enough to usefully answer how to avoid upsetting them.

Comment: I believe the specifics of the situation are irrelevant.  The character is going to die, the player is likely to take it badly.  What can and should I do to keep him from leaving the group afterwards?

Comment: Still interested to know why you, the DM, who is in total control of the universe, were so sure that they were going to die.

Comment: That is the correct answer. @ThomasMarkov sometimes, you can predict how careless or tactically inept a player can be.  Not always, but sometimes.